# C# My ArrayList only contains the last item

Tags: c#, matlab

I have the following code in C# Visual Studio.I am trying to plot data using MATLAB through COM server. I am able to do so somewhat, but with the code I have, the MATLAB output console only shows the last value for the variable "numbers" and when it plots, it overwrites all the previous values. Also, how can i make the variable size dynamic?My goal is to plot the data real time. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;

     namespace ConsoleApplication4
      {
         class Program
         {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ////// Create the MATLAB instance 
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[11];
            numbers[j] = j * 15;
            matlab.Execute("numbers");
            matlab.PutWorkspaceData("A", "base",numbers);
            matlab.Execute("plot(A);");
        }
        //    //Console.WriteLine(j*15);
        //}
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE:

```
  var numbers = new List<int>();
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            //numbers[j] = j * 15;
           int val= j * 15;
            numbers.Add(val);
            var array = numbers.ToArray();
            matlab.Execute("array");
            matlab.PutWorkspaceData("A", "base", array);
            matlab.Execute("plot(A);");
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not initialize `numbers` inside the loop. That would create a new instance every time.

Try this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[11];
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
  numbers[j] = j * 15;
  //double vIn = Convert.ToDouble(numbers);
  matlab.Execute("numbers");
  matlab.PutWorkspaceData("A", "base",numbers);
  matlab.Execute("plot(A);");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To make the array of dynamic size. Use `List<>`.
Then you have to alter the loop as such:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
  int val = j * 15;
  numbers.Add(val);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes @Sabi3023 already provided the solution. Would you happen to know how can I make the array size arbitrary or dynamic in this line: 
int[] numbers = new int[11]; ie. change 11 to a dynamic value

Comment: yes I had tried that myself before, but it results into an error.

Comment: What error? I am not sure how matlab works but you probably need to execute matlab functions after the for loop.

Comment: @DashD, that should do the trick. Converting the list to array maybe because matlab function expects an array. Good for you!

Answer (score 1):

you must move this line
    `int[] numbers = new int[11];`
 before of for loop

and place it after

```
'MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();'
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. I am coding in C# first time, so it is a big learning curve.